# What happens if I accidentally commit config/env file: local.branch.env, to Gitlab, that should have been added to the gitignore?

Tags: gitlab, jira, smart-commits

I mistatakely performed:
git add .
git commit ..
git push tomybranch

Checked Jira and realized config file is also added. I quickly deleted the branch and made same new branch and committed again rest of the code. It does not show up in pull request and commits are squashed showing 1 commit in MR. But still show up if I check the commits in jira. How can I delete that specific commit? Will I need to inform that to my team? Or will I get fired for this?

deleted branch made new same branch and committed new commits again clean again.